# Fetching a file from a Pod via OpenShift API

Tags: openshift

I would like to regularly pull a specific file from several containers hosted on OpenShift.
The manual describes how to copy a file from a container using the "oc" command - like so:

```
$ oc rsync devpod1234:/src /home/user/source
```

but - as stated - I would like to achieve the same using API calls. I googled and searched the API documentation but I didn't find anything describing how to read or write a file from a container via the API. Is that possible at all?

My goal is, that the utility would get my API Token and the containers' names as input and would then pull said file from those pods.

I am considering doing an exec using the oc-command mentioned above but I would prefer using the API. IMHO that would be more elegant, more efficient, and what-the-heck do we have an API for?  ;-)

**Did I bump into a showstopper?:**  :-(

When trying an approach using `oc rsync` I got:

```
C:\Users\someuser> oc rsync "test-pod-6bdc6dd8f5-qspvz:/test/test.txt" .
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:58608 -> 31346
Forwarding from [::1]:58608 -> 31346
Handling connection for 58608
E1223 14:51:21.701720   15896 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 58608 -> 31346: error forwarding port 31346 to pod f8b43e3125ed4a22985e6e550939a062786e974a05f4d4918a7e7648a8f58cf0, uid : port forward into network namespace "/var/run/netns/03d5b62b-f080-4141-8c37-e9f04a297be2": failed to connect to localhost:31346 inside namespace f8b43e3125ed4a22985e6e550939a062786e974a05f4d4918a7e7648a8f58cf0: dial tcp [::1]:31346: connect: connection refused
E1223 14:51:21.703564   15896 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
WARNING: cannot use rsync-daemon: rsync not available in container
```

Obviously, our containers don't have rsync installed. Outch!

Is there any other means to fetch a file from an OpenShift pod via "oc" or using any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for copying files from a container. If you look at how the `kubectl cp` command works (e.g. by running `kubectl -v8 cp ...`), you'll see that it is simply using an `exec` action to run `tar` inside the container (and then extracts the archive in the client).

Running:

```
kubectl cp examplepod:/etc/hosts hosts
```

Results in:

```
POST https://192.168.1.201:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/examplepod/exec?command=tar&command=cf&command=-&command=%2Fetc%2Fhosts&container=example&stderr=true&stdout=true
```

Which as you can see is running:

```
tar cf - /etc/hosts
```

That is pretty much the same mechanism used by `oc rsync`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. So I guess, I will need to implement something very similar using `exec` and `oc rsync`. Or implement this as cmd-file right away.

Comment: Trying to go down the exec-path I bumped into an issue that could mean: end-of-road - no way here. :-(   I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried using tar instead of rsync? Or just ‘cat’ if you’re fetching a text file.

Comment: `tar cf - /etc/hosts` yields me `$ tar cf - /etc/hosts
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
$`. With an appended ` | cat` I can see the file's content, but that still doesn't copy the content to my system but I need to manually copy-paste it over. The purpose of my attempts would be to actually be able to copy a file from a pod over to a local file.

Comment: It looks like you've enabled terminal mode (like `kubectl exec -it -- cmd ...`); you need to ensure that you **do not** request a terminal (`kubectl exec -- cmd ...`)