# oc rsync command on WIndows always yielding "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: openshift, rsync

I am trying to copy files from a pod running on an OpenShift cluster to my local Windows system.
My first attempt was `oc rsync <podname>:<path_to_file_on_pod> C:\temp`

That ended in an error message interestingly telling me that rsync isn't available (which turned out to be true) and that I should install `cwRsync` (an rsync implementation using Cygwin to run on Windows) and then try again.
So I downloaded and installed `cwrsync_6.2.11_x64_free.zip`, unzipped it and added its `bin` directory to my `path` and restarted my shell.

With Cygwin as a basis for the tool comes that one can not use the normal Windows path but needs to specify paths to e.g. C:\temp... as "/cygdrive/c/temp/...".

This Rsync/cwRsync seems to work - executing e.g.
`rsync /cygdrive/c/temp/folder1/test.txt /cygdrive/c/temp/folder2`
faithfully copied a test-file from `folder1` to `folder2`.

But as soon as I prefix this command with `oc` this always fails claiming that it could not find the Windows-side path. E.g.:

`oc rsync "test-pod-6bdc6dd8f5-qspvz:/temp/test" /cygdrive/c/temp/`

yields

`error: invalid path /cygdrive/c/temp/: CreateFile /cygdrive/c/temp/: The system cannot find the path specified.`

It doesn't seem to depend on the location (I also tried other destination paths but always with the same error result). No matter what path I specify, it can not be found.

Any idea what I am missing here?

BTW: I even tried a local operation only, i.e. not copying from a pod but on my local machine only:
`oc rsync /cygdrive/c/temp/folder1/test.txt /cygdrive/c/temp/folder2` (i.e. a local rsync only) but even that yields the same "error: invalid path /cygdrive/c/temp/folder1/test.txt: CreateFile /cygdrive/c/temp/folder1/test.txt: The system cannot find the path specified."

Answer (score 0):

Since rsync has two strategies "rsync, tar", you don't need to install rsync or cyg on your Windows machine, just make sure your pod has tar installed in the image. And to download the file, assuming you have a folder created in c drive "temp"

```
oc rsync test-pod-6bdc6dd8f5-qspvz:/temp/test C:/temp
```

Comment: It started up now without an error message re. path not found but ended in another error `cannot use rsync-daemon: rsync not available in container` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77704262/fetching-a-file-from-a-pod-via-openshift-api/77704359.  Not so easy to get hold of a file on a container with openshift. :-(

Comment: Ahh, this comes when you don't have tar installed in the pod, just check by typing "tar" in the pod terminal, if not try to use a docker image that has tar.